# Persisted Changes in Grails not showing up in application

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have just started developing a Grails app froma tutorial today, and I have noticed that when I save changes to Domain objects, the changes aren't being reflected immediately throughout the application.

I have a simple Account object that is used to login to the app, and I have the basic Grails scaffolding providing CRUD functionality to change the object.

Once logged on, the index.gsp displays a welcome with information from the user's Account object (biography, description etc) - however, if i change the Account description (using the scaffolded CRUD) and return to index the change is not reflected (although if i view the default list.gsp page for the Accounts the change is reflected there).

**---EDIT---**

The account domain object is the object that we use o authenticate/login with.
an exmple index sinppet looks like this:

```
<p class="header">${session.user.login}'s Profile</p>
```

This just displays a welcome to the user - However, if i go to the account controller CRUD page and change the user name (login) then it isn't reflected in the index (even after complete refresh of browser).  I have noticed that if I leave it to expire the session and then log back in again it is all good.. Should I be getting the account object by some means other than by the session.user?

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but when you return to the index, are you actually refreshing the page or just using the back button?

Comment: I have tried using the scaffolding "home" button as well as doing a hard refresh on the index page.

Comment: What version of Grails?  And what tutorial are you using (link?)

Comment: Its Grails 1.3.7.  The tutorial is actually a PDF someone gave me called GettingStartedWithGrails (its an e-book) - couldnt find a link online that you didnt need to register for.  The Domain class is just a simple class with a few fields and the controller save/list/etc is all straight from "grails generate-all Account"

Comment: Can you show/reference your `save` and `index` action code?

Comment: Are you flushing immediately when saving? Like doing domainObject.save(flush: true) or just domainObject.save() ?

Comment: we are just doing a save(flush:true).

It has been suggested that it could be related to lazy loading but I have tried to configure these differently and had no joy..

Another point that I failed to mention is that the updates are not directly on the account object, but they are at account.profile.bio for example - so i thought it may be to do with the account object not being refreshed when i make a change to the profile object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have resolved this - so the session.user wasn't being updatedvdruing the session.

I just created a custom tagLib to get the current user and display the relevant details rather than try to extract them straight from session.user..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know [Getting Started with Grails](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started). It's very good for starter, though there's some not-updated details. As I remember, its default homepage have the information about the controllers, but not any domain object?

About your question, I think you should check the code of home webpage/ and controller file. It's in `\grails-app\views` and `\grails-app\controller`.

Comment: Thanks Hoang, I have had a look in the views and controllers, and they are just the generated scaffolding code for the basic CRUD operations.